# How can I set an Image to an Image control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, image, uri

I'm trying to do this:

```
imgUser.Source = new Uri(user.Photo);
```

But I'm getting an error that I cannot convert a URI to an ImageSource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(VS.95).aspx) is an ImageSource and can be created from a Uri:

```
imgUser.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(user.Photo));
```